# How to change and access reactjs state in a same function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm kinda new to reactjs and I got a situation where I will have to change a state and then I will need to access the new state value in the same function. Please have a look at the code below,

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true); // default state true

  const CallMe = () => {
    setState(false); // state change to false
    console.log(state); // expecting false but return true
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={CallMe}>CallMe</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click the button for first time, I get true when I'm expecting false. Is there anyway, I can do it these thing in a same function like above?

Comment: if you need a state right away u usually dont use a state but a variable. const let

Comment: In your example it is harmless and okay, but usually it is an indicator of bad coding practices if you need to rely on a state value you just set earlier in the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state` is asynchronous. you need to wait till state update. use `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state)
}, [state])
```

Comment: There is no way, I can do it inside the CallMe function?

Comment: use the second argument in setState. `setState(false, () => console.log(state))`

Comment: not working, showing an error: Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

Comment: then you have to use the useEffect

Answer (score 0):

React states are asynchronous, so in the below line of code the state has not been changed yet:

```
console.log(state);
```

You should use `useEffect` to see changes:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true); // default state true

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state)
  }, [state])

  const CallMe = () => {
    setState(false); 
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={CallMe}>CallMe</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```